# Seaborn catplot Sort by Count column

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization, visualization

### Problem

I have data looks like the following:

| Month | Product | SalesCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 94 |
| 1 | 6 | 38 |
| 1 | 2 | 56 |
| 1 | 7 | 47 |

I would like:

- Display a histogram and sort them by `SalesCount`, from highest to lowest.
- Display all labels and titles.

### What I've Tried

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

rng = np.random.default_rng()

dft = pd.DataFrame({'Month': 1,
                    'Product': rng.choice(30, size=30, replace=False),
                    'SalesCount': np.random.randint(1, 100, 30),
                    })

# Try to sort the dataframe
#dft = dft.sort_values(by=['SalesCount'])

print(dft)

g = sns.catplot(data=dft, kind='bar', x='Product', y='SalesCount', height=6, aspect=1.8, facecolor=(0.3,0.3,0.7,1))
#, order=dft[['Product', 'SalesCount']].index
(g.set_axis_labels('Product', 'Count')
    .set_titles('test'))
```

Which shows chart similar to this:

[image: Count by Months]

I have tried sorting the dataframe first (`dft = dft.sort_values(by=['SalesCount'])`) and also add `order` parameter (`order=dft[['Product', 'SalesCount']].index`) to `sns.catplot` method. Both of these attempts don't sort the histogram.

The second issue I have is adding the titles. I have tried `.set_titles('test')` in `FacetGrid` (from `sns.catplot`) instance, but title would not show up.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that when trying to pass `order` you need to sort your values before getting the index? Otherwise the index is (probably) in ascending numerical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to make your `Product` column a string instead of an integer.  This should work.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

rng = np.random.default_rng()

dft = pd.DataFrame({'Month': 1,
                    'Product': rng.choice(30, size=30, replace=False),
                    'SalesCount': np.random.randint(1, 100, 30),
                    })

# Try to sort the dataframe
dft = dft.sort_values(by=['SalesCount'])
dft['Product'] = dft['Product'].astype(str)


print(dft)
g = sns.catplot(data=dft, kind='bar', x='Product', y='SalesCount', height=6, aspect=1.8, facecolor=(0.3,0.3,0.7,1))
#, order=dft[['Product', 'SalesCount']].index
(g.set_axis_labels('Product', 'Count')
    .set_titles('test'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Chris... do you know the reason why it has to be `str` ? I thought Seaborn should be able to sort by integer too..?

Comment: @stack247 Not entirely sure, you'd probably have to look at the source code, or at least triple check the documentation to see why that behavior happens